# Excel: Count number of values matching a criteria and present in another list

Tags: excel

I have a couple of lists which contain employee names and a product ID. There is another list of product IDs which are supposed to be sold (this list is larger).

I already have a COUNTIF formula to get the total sales by an agent. Now I need to see just the number of those that are in the target list.

Could you advise as to the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you already have the count using COUNTIF, below formula will help to match the products:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"Present in tobe sold list","not present in tobe list")`

where column A has the products sold by agents and B has the list of products to be sold, the larger list

.[image]

Hope this works!